# I have a syntax issue between <span> and a "data-text" I am using for a scrolling text

Tags: html, css, syntax

I am using data-text for a scrolling text and to make it infinite scroll.
But there is different styling in text in the same line and I am using  to change styling.

But it seems like the data-text won't accept this syntax... 
How could I style my text in the same way I did for scrolling but without  styling ?

```html
<div class="defileParent">

<p class="defile" 
data-text="

<span style="color: black; font-family: Roboto-MediumItalic; font-size: 18px;">EXPOSITION</span>       
<span style="color: black; font-family: Van-Dijk-ICG-Bold; font-size: 32px;"><u>QG</u></span>        
<span style="color: black; font-family: Roboto-MediumItalic; font-size: 18px;">DE</span>       
<span style="color: black; font-family: Van-Dijk-ICG-Bold; font-size: 32px;"><u>Fanny Durand</u></span>        
<span style="color: black; font-family: Roboto-MediumItalic; font-size: 18px;">DU</span>       
<span style="color: black; font-family: Van-Dijk-ICG-Bold; font-size: 32px;"><u>06.07.19</u></span>       
<span style="color: black; font-family: Roboto-MediumItalic; font-size: 18px;">AU</span>       
<span style="color: black; font-family: Van-Dijk-ICG-Bold; font-size: 32px;"><u>15.09.19</u></span>

">

<span style="color: black; font-family: Roboto-MediumItalic; font-size: 18px;">EXPOSITION</span>       
<span style="color: black; font-family: Van-Dijk-ICG-Bold; font-size: 32px;"><u>QG</u></span>        
<span style="color: black; font-family: Roboto-MediumItalic; font-size: 18px;">DE</span>       
<span style="color: black; font-family: Van-Dijk-ICG-Bold; font-size: 32px;"><u>Fanny Durand</u></span>        
<span style="color: black; font-family: Roboto-MediumItalic; font-size: 18px;">DU</span>       
<span style="color: black; font-family: Van-Dijk-ICG-Bold; font-size: 32px;"><u>06.07.19</u></span>       
<span style="color: black; font-family: Roboto-MediumItalic; font-size: 18px;">AU</span>       
<span style="color: black; font-family: Van-Dijk-ICG-Bold; font-size: 32px;"><u>15.09.19</u></span>

</p>
</div>
```

```css
.defileParent {
  z-index:51;
    margin: 0em auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
  bottom:7px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width:110%;
  letter-spacing: .06rem;
}

.defile {
    z-index:55;
    display: block;
    -webkit-animation:linear marqueelike 20s infinite ;
    -moz-animation:linear marqueelike 20s infinite ;
    -o-animation:linear marqueelike 20s infinite ;
    -ms-animation:linear marqueelike 20s infinite ;
    animation:linear marqueelike 20s infinite ;
    margin-left:-100%;
    padding:0 5px;
    text-align:left;
    height:25px;
}


.defile:after {
    content:attr(data-text);
    position:absolute;
    white-space:nowrap;
    padding-left:10px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes marqueelike {
    0%, 100% {margin-left:0;}
    99.99% {margin-left:-100%;}
 }
@-moz-keyframes marqueelike {
    0%, 100% {margin-left:0;}
    99.99% {margin-left:-100%;}
 }
@-o-keyframes marqueelike {
    0%, 100% {margin-left:0;}
    99.99% {margin-left:-100%;}
 }
@-ms-keyframes marqueelike {
    0%, 100% {margin-left:0;}
    99.99% {margin-left:-100%;}
 }
@keyframes marqueelike {
    0%, 100% {margin-left:0;}
    99.99% {margin-left:-100%;}
 }
```

Comment: You have opened the `data-text` with double quote marks. Did you notice the double quotes in `styles` within the `data-text` as well?

Comment: ok so this is the issue, but what should I bypass this problem ?

Comment: Did you try using single quote mark inside `data-text`?

Comment: It's not working....